# mdwtools' syntax for BNF with beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, incompatibility, mdwtools

When I `\usepackage{syntax}` inside a `beamer` presentation, the angle brackets on the right-hand side of rules either come up as `¡` and `¿` or as wide angle brackets `<` and `>`, instead of the thin ones on the left-hand side. Also the text is not italicized.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident>
\end{grammar}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong output with beamer]

If instead I change the `documentclass` to `article` and remove the `frame` environment, I get the expected output:

[image: Correct output with article]

How can I get the correct output with beamer? I think it has to do with beamer's overlay syntax which uses `<` and `>`, but I didn't find anything in the `syntax` package's docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `fragile` option to the `frame`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident>
\end{grammar}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't fix the shape of the brackets nor the italics, though.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: It does now. I forgot the `fragile` option.

Comment: T1 is not necessary; the key is `fragile`, because the grammar environment changes the category codes.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Good to know. Had no idea about `syntax` and grammar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate! However, I never seem to understand the mechanics of fragile/robust in LaTeX. Your answer helped me too, but *why*?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `savebox` to typeset the grammar outside the `frame` environment works (and you can reuse the same box for several frames):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident>
\end{grammar}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}
  \usebox{\mybox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of full beamer slide with correct rendering]